# Android select in ListView and push button to select

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a ListView populated with the names of US states from a database.  To transition to a new screen, I want to select a state in that ListView and then hit a button that transitions to a screen of cities in that state.

I think I know how to populate the ListView, but I do not know what the inner button workings should look like.  Plus, I do not know how to use to carry the state info through the transition to use it to list cities.

Does this code have anything to do with this?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            blah.setCurrentListID(arg3);
```

Let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, assuming you use an adapter class that extends ArrayAdapter with states, like:

```
public class StatesItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UsState>
```

Then you have a List like ArrayList as the data source for the ArrayAdapter right? Then,

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

        UsState state = statesList.get(position); // on ArrayList
        // or try   statesList.get(listView.getSelectedItemPosition());


        Intent citiesIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CitiesActivity.class);
        citiesIntent.putExtra("state_name", state.getName()); // Name string originating from database record
        startActivity(citiesIntent);
}
```

And then in the Cities Activity, in onCreate you must get the name of the state and use it as a criteria in your database query to get a Cursor of city results:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle bundleExtras = intent.getExtras();

            String selectedState = bundleExtras.getString("state_name");

            // Do database query on cities relating to state
            .......
```

Comment: I get the error Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
 - void is an invalid type for the variable 
  onItemClick
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected                                                                      
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected                      in the code:  _italic_public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){_italic_

Comment: I do not understand the necessity of:  public class StatesItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UsState>